# Passing the selected value of dropdown list to a php variable before submitting the form

Tags: php, dropdown, onchange

I am using the code below to pass the selected value of a dropdown list to the php variable "pack". This is done by refreshing the page once the value of the dropdown list is selected. The dropdown list is part of a lightbox form which appears as a pop-up window. The main problem is that  instead of the pop-up window of the lightbox form (where the drowpdown is) to just be refreshed, the entire page behind/before it is refreshed. So, in this way, the lightbox form is disappeared and appears again once the user presses again the Book Now button (of the behind page); in this way, the selected value is shown in the form. Is it possible that only the pop-up window is refreshed? I look forward to your help.

```
  <select style="width: 200px;" id="myselect" name="pack" onchange="window.location='index.php? 
  id='+this.value+'&pos='+this.selectedIndex;">
    <option value="" selected disabled>Select your package</option>
    <option value="1">Package 1</option>
    <option value="2">Package 2</option>
    <option value="3">Package 3</option>
  </select>

  <?php
  if(isset($_GET['id']))
  {
     $pack=$_GET['id'];
     echo $pack;
  ?>
   <script>
      var myselect = document.getElementById("myselect");
      myselect.options.selectedIndex = <?php echo $_GET["pos"]; ?>
   </script>
   <?php
   }
   ?>
```

Comment: Yup, it’s called ajax. Google jquery and ajax

Answer (score 0):

You should be using JavaScript & AJAX calls for this, here's some code for you, change it how you like:

> **index.php**

```
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<select style="width: 200px;" id="myselect" onchange="packSelected">
    <option value="" selected disabled>Select your package</option>
    <option value="1">Package 1</option>
    <option value="2">Package 2</option>
    <option value="3">Package 3</option>
</select>

<script>
    function packSelected () {
        // pack has been selected, make ajax request to php to process the selection
        $.post("packSelection.php",
            {
                // pass POST parameter 'packId' with the value of the dropdown selection
                packId: $('#myselect').val(),
            },
            function(data, status){
                // check status is success, this is a text version of the status code provided by ajax
                if (status === 'success') {
                    // decode the json we gave back from our php into an object
                    data = JSON.parse(data);
                    // check our php could process the input
                    if (data.result) {
                        // it could, do what you want
                        alert('AJAX Request Successful, packId: '+data.packId);
                    } else {
                        alert('AJAX Error: '+data.error);
                    }
                } else {
                    alert('AJAX Request Failed');
                }
            });
    }
</script>
```

> **packSelection.php**

```
<?php
// uncomment line below to access session data about the user, if you are using a login system, useful to do stuff with the pack id
// session_start();

// define return content type
header('Content-Type: application/json');

// check packId is set
if (isset($_POST['packId'])) {
    $packId = $_POST['packId'];
    // DO WHATEVER YOU WANT WITH THE PACK ID HERE.
    // MAYBE:
    //   - Assign packId to the user through MySQL

    // tell AJAX we successfully processed the request and return the packId, could be useful
    echo json_encode(array('result' => 'true', 'packId' => $packId));
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('result' => 'false', 'error' => 'packId is not defined'));
}
```

If you need any help, comment, good luck.

Comment: I have used your suggested code, but unfortunately it is not working. I have tested it by writing  <?php echo $packId ?> in my lightbox-form.php file where the dropdown list is ( the file is not index.php), and it does not give any outcome.

Comment: can you please provide some more help on this?